# Magento 2.2.3 Account Dasbhoard: Order History Blank display

Tags: orders, customer-account, magento2.2.3

Hello I encountered problem when checking out a product from the store. After successful checkout I went to my Account dashboard and navigate to "Order History" but unfortunately it will just display a white blank. Any ideas guys?

This is my Order History page looks like even I successfully  checked out a product.

[image]

Here's the error from System.log

> [2018-06-06 01:58:01] main.CRITICAL: Constructor failed [] []
>   [2018-06-06 01:58:06] main.WARNING: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'seller.menu.wrapper'. [] []
>   [2018-06-06 01:58:07] main.CRITICAL: Constructor failed [] []
>   [2018-06-06 01:58:07] main.INFO: SELECT DISTINCT  `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`image`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`color`, `e`.`color_value`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`swatch_image`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`sm_featured`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `mv`.*, MAX(logged_at) AS `max_loged`, COUNT(`event_id`) AS `num_view_counts`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = '1'
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='2'
>    LEFT JOIN `report_event` AS `mv` ON mv.object_id = e.entity_id
>    LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (mv.event_type_id = 1 AND mv.subject_id=12 AND mv.store_id=1) GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `max_loged` DESC
>    LIMIT 15 [] []
>   [2018-06-06 01:58:07] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.name' in 'field list', query was: SELECT DISTINCT  `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`image`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`color`, `e`.`color_value`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`swatch_image`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`sm_featured`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `mv`.*, MAX(logged_at) AS `max_loged`, COUNT(`event_id`) AS `num_view_counts`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = '1'
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='2'
>    LEFT JOIN `report_event` AS `mv` ON mv.object_id = e.entity_id
>    LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (mv.event_type_id = 1 AND mv.subject_id=12 AND mv.store_id=1) GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `max_loged` DESC
>    LIMIT 15 [] []

I turned the site to developer's mode and found this error after navigating to account dashboard My Order history.

[image]

Comment: can you check system.log

Comment: Hello @PrashantPatel I have updated the post with the error log from system.log. Thanks

Comment: You are checking wrong order history tab. The tab you are checking is for order placed by someone else with your products as you are a vendor(according to th screenshot). You need to check the tab "My Orders".

Comment: Hello @SukumarGorai, Yes I tried checking also the My Orders tab but still the same problem it is blank.

Comment: Can you disable the marketplace extension and test if its working fine or not? The error is something related to marketplace extension you have installed.

Comment: Hello, I tried that one last night. I disabled them one by one. and even disabled all the third party extensions. But still, I'm getting the same error. Any idea?